# Detecting the change of the font smoothing setting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, fonts, cleartype, smoothing

I have a page that uses @font-face and I am playing with the JavaScript code that conditionally sets the text in this typeface depending on whether the font smoothing is enabled. Detection is done along [these lines](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2009/11/29/how-to-detect-font-smoothing-using-javascript/), but a bit more elaborate to allow telling ClearType and Standard smoothing apart.

In any case the smoothing check is done on page load, and I want to understand if there is a way to capture the event of the smoothing preference changing once the page is loaded.

Thanks

Comment: You want to detect whether the user has changed the preference after the page has loaded?

Comment: Are you sure this makes sense? I mean, most users have never even seen the setting for font smoothing. Is it really necessary to prepare for the case that they change it while they're on your site?

Comment: @pekka - I'm just curious if this is possible to do, not if it makes any practical sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this that works without a timeout to do the check you show every x seconds - which of course is sub-optimal from a resource point of view.

I don't think there is any JavaScript event to hook into. The size of an element that contains text *might* change if the smoothing method changes, but then it also might not.

Comment: "The size of an element that contains text might change if the smoothing method changes, but then it also might not." --

Do you know this or is this a guess? If it's former, I'd love to see an example, because I was not able to find one myself and I did quite a bit of experimenting.

Comment: @Alex I built a primitive test here: http://jsfiddle.net/xJbw5/3/ and switched ClearType on and off. The difference is noticeable in the text, but the height value does not change, so I'm fairly sure it doesn't affect the physical dimensions of the element after all.

Comment: yeah, that's my observation too. In early ClearType announcements MS showed examples where the text was wider when the CT was on, but they got enough flak (regarding pixel-perfect page layouts getting screwed up) to make the production release stay within same width/height as non-CT renderings. What I was hoping to find with my probing was a combination of symbols in a specific font that would cause the width/height change. Tried lots of things - very small font sizes (1-2px), very large ones, negative letter spacing and what not - nothing seemed to trigger size difference.